# jQuery UI dialog's content shifts up after being populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, jquery

This is ASP.NET MVC 2.  Basically, I call an action in a controller with an AJAX call and the action returns me a partial view (so, some HTML).
I have a jQuery UI dialog which I populate on AJAX call back function.

```
$('#JqUiDialog').html(htmlResult);
$('#JqUiDialog').dialog('open');
```

IE7 seems to render this properly (what a surprise), FF on the other hand shifts all of the content up by about 90px.  This includes the title and the resize bar of the dialog.  Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?

```
    $('#JqUiDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Edit Address',
        hide: 'explode',
        show: 'fadeIn',
        width: 400,
        height: 300
    });
```

in HTML:  `<div id='#JqUiDialog'></div>`

EDIT:  Ok, the problem seems to happen when I have `<input type='text'/>` as part of the HTML that is returned by the partial view.  It's still puzzling me.

Comment: I did a lot of stuff with ui dialog and didn't had this kind of problem, look here http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/popupformdemo do you have here the same problem in your FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:  when creating dialog,

```
show: 'fadeIn'
```

is what messes it up for FireFox.